# Get stylesheet's path

Tags: front-end, filtering, files-and-directories, stylesheet

Is there a more idiomatic way to get stylesheet's path from its name? (assuming it is accessible for the FrontEnd)

```
Module[{
        found
      , i = 0
      , dirs = Reverse[ToFileName /@ AbsoluteCurrentValue[StyleSheetPath]]
    }
  , While[
        found = FileNames["Default.nb", dirs[[++i]]]
      ; Length[found] < 1 && i != Length[dirs]
    ]
  ; Last @ Prepend[found, $Failed]
]
```

The code above is suspiciously long for something as basic as that.

This does not count as it is too slow:

```
FileNames[
    "Default.nb"
  , Reverse[ToFileName /@ AbsoluteCurrentValue[StyleSheetPath]]
]
```

Comment: This seems to work: `Block[{$Path = Join[$Path, Reverse[ToFileName /@ AbsoluteCurrentValue[StyleSheetPath]]]}, FindFile["Default.nb"] ]`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin @Kuba shouldn't `Block[{$Path = ToFileName /@ AbsoluteCurrentValue[StyleSheetPath]}, 
 FindFile["Default.nb"]]` be enough?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and Rolf, either way it won't be so easy, it seems that paclets directories are put at the end of `StyleSheetPath` while the list starts with `$UBDir -> $BDir -> $IDir`. So either we need to sort them or paclets styles are really the least specific. Though I'm too tired to check.

Comment: @RolfMertig ok, checked, paclet directories are really the least specific. So `Reverse` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built on Rolf's and Leonid's suggestions, a general function for that:

```
FindStyleSheet[] := FindStyleSheet[EvaluationNotebook[]];

FindStyleSheet[nb_NotebookObject] := FindStyleSheet[
    CurrentValue[nb, StyleDefinitions]
];

FindStyleSheet[stylesheet : (_FileName | _FrontEnd`FileName)] := 
  FindStyleSheet @ ToFileName @ stylesheet;

FindStyleSheet[string_String?FileExistsQ] := string;


    (*this is the core one but I extendend definitions*)

FindStyleSheet[string_String] := Block[
    {$Path = ToFileName /@ AbsoluteCurrentValue[StyleSheetPath]}
  , FindFile[string]
];



FindStyleSheet[___]:=Failure[
    "argpatt"
  , "Message" -> StringTemplate[General::argpatt][FindStyleSheet]
]
```

So even if you set the stylesheet to `Wolfram / Demonstrations` it will return:

```
FindStyleSheet[]
```

> ```
> "[...] \\ Mathematica \\ 11.0 \\ SystemFiles \\ FrontEnd \\ StyleSheets \\ Wolfram \\ Demonstration.nb"
> ```