# How to programmatically open the Stylesheet of the current notebook

Tags: stylesheet

How do you programmatically open the stylesheet of the current notebook?  I can choose the "Edit Stylesheet..." menu item with my mouse, but I can't find a way to do it programmatically. I was hoping for something like

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["Stylesheet"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This plus NotebookOpen: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138764/5478

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["EditStyleDefinitions"]
```